# Delete a duplicate object in array when fill one by one

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects that some of them are the same (duplicate).
in a loop of .forEach(). inside a callback function i want to remove a duplicate object when they enter to another array one by one. i tried to loop every iteration on the array to find and remove duplicate but for some reason i can not get it.

I tried to make a loop and slice the duplicate.
I can not make a function.
I can not get the whole array and handle the duplicates.

```
.forEach(function(snap){

groupsJoin.push({groupId: snap)}

groupsJoin.sort((a, b) => (a.groupId > b.groupId) ? -1 : 1)

for (z=1; z<groupsJoin.length; z++) {
     if (groupsJoin[z-1].groupId === groupsJoin[z].groupId) {
         groupsJoin = groupsJoin.slice(0, z)
     }



...Object.assign({}, groupsJoin)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove all the duplicates?

Comment: yes all of them

Comment: Are you tying to mutate the array with a method of the array itself? very bad. use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead, the right data structure to hold unique values. If you need an algorithm to filter out duplicates in place, then you can scan your array with forEach, mark deleteable objects adding a boolean flag, then run a filter which inclued only object witouth that property

Comment: Include some sample data and desired output from that data.

Comment: @TalTalmon Are some array members _the same object_ , or actually different objects of _the same shape_? In the first case using a Set as mentioned will work, otherwise it won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Set data structure. Just create a new Set by passing the array and it will automatically remove duplicates

```
let set1 = new Set(yourArray)
```

For more information, see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Answer (score 1):

In case you can't use `new Set(groupsJoin)` to filter all of them at once, you refer to the following solution :

```
var groupsJoin = new Set(); 
arr.forEach(x => groupsJoin.add(x))
```

As result, you'll get an array with unique values.
if there is need to keep maps inside, instead of **x**, use

```
x.groupId => groupsJoin.add(x.groupId)
```

It will depend on your context.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 9, 8, 11, 1];

var groupsJoin = new Set();
arr.forEach( x => groupsJoin.add(x));

console.log(groupsJoin);
```

Comment: The solution works on NodeJS for sure and Chrome console. Checked.